# How .Net 6 application can run a project with .Net 5 reference?

Tags: .net, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have an API project that upgraded from .net 5 to .net 6. And this project uses a class library project with .net 5. I can run it without any problem. But I don't understand how this application can use .net 5 without any .net 5 runtimes or SDK. How it is possible?